# Should the adjective "problem" not be used before a noun?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

According to the Merriam-Webster's dictionary, the word "**problem**" is defined as an adjective as follows:

> *problem*
>
> adjective
>
> Usage: **always** used before a noun
>
> :difficult to deal with
>
> - a *problem* child

However, I have seen in some article the following predicative usage of the word "problem":

> Constructing the relevant knowledge base was *problem* enough.

I wonder whether it is grammatical to use the adjective "problem" predicatively.

Comment: It isn't an adjective in that sentence - it means '...was enough of a problem'.

Comment: @KateBunting You mean the word "problem" is a noun in that sentence?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @KateBunting If it is a noun, so why does it not have any article?

Comment: @Later - not all nouns are preceded by articles.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes. But, the zero article is used for plural nouns, uncountable nouns, nouns in some idioms, and some other special cases. I cannot see such cases for the word "problem" in that sentence.

Comment: @Later: Well, perhaps it's an idiom. Two of these examples have uncountable nouns in and two don't: "Had we but world enough and time", "Are you man enough?", "There's food enough", "’Twas grief enough to think mankind..."

Comment: It was shame enough to be beaten at tennis by a nine-year-old girl.

Comment: I don't think your example *Constructing the relevant knowledge base **was problem enough*** is syntactically valid, even though it's not uncommon. Imho it's just sloppy colloquial spoken shorthand for ***...was enough of a problem***. And I suggest ***no-one*** would dispense with the article in that syntactically valid longer form. Having said that, I have no problem with either sequence in *Don't bother me now! I have **problems enough**!* and *...I have **enough problems**!*

Comment: It's an unusual construction for English. I don't know what it's called (maybe BillJ will pop in), but it's definitely a noun.

Comment: @gotube - it's [not all that unusual](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22was+problem+enough%22).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I said the structure is "unusual" for English, as in a grammatical oddity, not that it's "uncommon".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I saw that sentence in a well-known magazine. Is it appropriate to use such a colloquial construction in formal writing?

Comment: @Later: No, I don't really think ***X was problem enough** [without Y]* is suitable for "formal" contexts. But I think much the same about ***X was enough of a problem...*** purely because the *meaning* in both cases seems a bit "chatty, subjective". But as other comments imply, ***problem enough*** might be even more problematic in a formal context because of the "unusual, peculiar" syntax (unless you *want* your text to sound a bit "quirky", which is sometimes appropriate). A possible alternative might be something like ***There were some problems with X***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enough is sometimes used after nouns. The reversal is a form of emphasis. It is a little old fashioned and literary, and is acceptable in formal writing. Example - "Columbia College Today: At the same time, the space demands of teaching and research are ever growing, ever expanding. That Columbia does not have enough space today is problem enough"

The noun can be in a singular or plural form.

Don’t ask questions – there’ll be time enough for that later.

He had reason enough to be angry

I was fool enough to trust her

A gâteau weighing 2 Kg should be cake enough for anybody.

> Had we but world enough and time,
> This coyness, lady, were no crime.
> We would sit down, and think which way
> To walk, and pass our long love’s day.
>
> Andrew Marvell (1621-1678) *To His Coy Mistress*

But are these reasons enough to justify their continued use?

Brazil has problems enough of its own

[Enough (Macmillan Dictionary)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/enough_1)

Comment: Marvell's [poem](https://poets.org/poem/his-coy-mistress) famously points out that 'The Grave's a fine and private place,
But none I think do there embrace.'

Comment: Wikipedia has an article on *postpositive adjectives*.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective

Comment: I'm not sure if *enough* is an adjective or a determiner, but maybe it works the same.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you for your answer. Can we conclude that "... was enough of a problem" is more suitable for **formal writing** than "... was problem enough"?

Comment: @Later - 'problem enough' is fine in formal writing. Example - "Columbia College Today:  At the same time, the space demands of teaching and research are ever growing, ever expanding. That Columbia does not have enough space today is problem enough"